# Eclipse project generation : add an 'excluding' attribute to classpath entry

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Gradle generates well my eclipse .classpath content with such lines as :

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
```

But what I want is really :

```
<classpathentry excluding="**/.DS_Store" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**/.DS_Store" kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
```

How can I customise gradle to add this 'excluding' attribute on the fly when generating the eclipse project ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by using `withXml`

From the gradle user guide:

Example 36.5. Customizing the XML

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

eclipse.wtp.facet.file.withXml { provider ->
    provider.asNode().fixed.find { it.@facet == 'jst.java' }.@facet = 'jst2.java'
}
```

Here is the link:

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html